# Can't use string as a HASH reference

Tags: perl, hash

Here's the structure that I'm trying to access

```
Dumper $resourceAudit

$VAR1 = '{
  \'rh6\' => {
                    \'h\' => 1,
                    \'n\' => 1
                  },
  \'win2k8\' => {
                     \'h\' => 1,
                     \'n\' => 1
                   },
  \'win2k12\' => {
                        \'h\' => 3,
                        \'n\' => 3
                      },
  \'win2k3\' => {
                     \'h\' => 0,
                     \'n\' => 1
                   },
  \'usim\' => {
                               \'h\' => 4,
                               \'n\' => 4
                             }
}';
```

So, I know that $resourceAudit is actually a string and so, `%$resourceAudit` is sure to give me the `Can't use string as a HASH reference` error.

Is there any way I can get around this and access the `'rh6'` key?

Comment: You can try use [`eval`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) to convert the string into a Perl hash first

Comment: If you go the `eval` route, make sure the variable doesn't contain any malicious code.

Comment: In case this is not clear to you: Your variable contains a string representation of the data structure, not the data structure itself. You can see that because the quotes are escaped `\'rh6\'`, and because the error message says _can't use **string** as a HASH reference_. So `eval` is your best bet, like @HåkonHægland says.

Comment: `%{ eval $resourceAudit };` worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$resourceAudit` doesn't contain a reference to a hash; it contains a string. That string is Perl code that would return a reference to a hash when executed. You can use `eval EXPR` to run Perl code.

```
my $data = eval($serialized_data)
   or die("Error executing audit code: $@");

... %$data ...
```